# Trying to format ggplot output

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2, data-visualization

I am trying to plot `WaterLevel` vs `Datetime` (I formatted the [datetime](/questions/tagged/datetime)), however I get an error like

> Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : 'to' must be a finite number

```
    library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(shiny)
library(stringi)

file = "http://dd.weather.gc.ca/hydrometric/csv/SK/hourly/SK_hourly_hydrometric.csv"
skdat <- read.csv(file, head=T, sep=",", dec=".", stringsAsFactors = F)
colnames(skdat) <- c("ID", "Date", "WaterLevel", "Grade1", "Symbol1",
                     "QAQC-1", "DischargeDebit", "Grade2", "Symbol2",
                     "QAQC-2")

subds <- subset(skdat, ID=='05EF001')
subds$datetime <- as.POSIXct(subds$Date, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H%m%S-06:00")
p2 <- ggplot(subds, aes(x = datetime, y = WaterLevel)) + geom_line()
p2
```

I have tried different formats and I know the data is good as it plots in a simple plot as well.

Comment: The dates in your date column are weird: they contain two different hours. This is not a standard datetime format. So when you try to convert them it produces NA's, and the error appears because you're attempting to plot NA's. What would you like the actual hour to be?

Comment: What is `06:00` in the datetime column?

Comment: Thanks Omry and TeeKea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use -

```
subds$datetime <- as.POSIXct(subds$Date, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS")#"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%m:%S-06:00")
```

This would cast your date properly to give the `datetime` column and not give `NA`s.

After this the plot will get generated -

[image]